# How to pass parameters in LHS Brackets format using rest client

Tags: java, spring-boot, strapi, rest-client, httpexchange

There is some API that involves passing parameters using LHS Brackets. Specifically, we are talking about the CMS Strapi API: https://docs.strapi.io/dev-docs/api/rest/parameters

I'm using spring boot 3.2.2 and want to implement integration using the built-in RestClient and HttpExchange interfaces.
Please tell me, is it possible to somehow specify transfer to LHS Brackets for HttpExchange and RequestParam?

Example request:

```
GET /api/categories?pagination[page]=1&pagination[pageSize]=10
```

Example of my HttpExchange interface:

```java
@HttpExchange("/categories")
public interface CategoryClient {

    @GetExchange
    StrapiResponse<List<Category>> find(CategoryRequest request);

}

public record CategoryRequest(@RequestParam("pagination") Pagination pagination) {
}

public record Pagination(Integer page, Integer pageSize) {
}
```